# Python code for import not working properly

Tags: python-2.7

I am testing below python code to export content from one txt file to another but in destination contents are getting copied with some different language (may be chinese) with improper

```
# - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-

from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script,from_file,to_file = argv

print "Does the output file exist ? %r" %exists(to_file)
print "If 'YES' hit Enter to proceed or terminate by CTRL+C "
raw_input('?')

infile=open(from_file)
file1=infile.read()

outfile=open(to_file,'w')
file2=outfile.write(file1)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: You can copy file 1 to file 2 with python, instead of using read / write method.

Comment: Actually I was trying to test read and write function in my code hence didn't utilized the copy file option.Anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to copy 1 file to another :

```
with open("from_file") as f:
   with open("to_file", "w") as f1:
       for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```

Comment: I was trying to test the read and write function because my end goal is read data from text file and load it into a .csv file.I am able to figure it out and code is working now.Thank you for suggestion.